# List column filtering issue

Tags: custom-list

I have created list , each column has assigned parent tasks so for example raw 1 to 5 has same parent task while 10 to 15 has another same parent task, it's grouped by parent task , when I filter it doesn't show all the parent tasks I select but only some.